# -Solved- Extracting Text after a tag using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

Given below code gives me output something like this,

```
<a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/uk-envoy-lays-wreath-at-jallianwala-bagh-memorial-expresses-deep-regret/articleshow/68860078.cms"><img border="0" hspace="10" align="left" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/68860078.cms" /></a>British High Commissioner to India Sir Dominic Asquith laid a wreath at the Jallianwala Bagh memorial here on Saturday on the centenary of the massacre and said Britain "deeply regretted" the suffering caused to the victims.
```

I'm trying to extract the text after `</a>` this tag

This is my code is there any method in jsoup that do the part or
something else I'm missing?

```
try {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128936835.cms").parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();
            Elements items = document.getElementsByTag("item");
            for (Element element : items) {
                String title = element.select("title").text();
                String link = element.select("link").text();
                String time = element.select("pubDate").text();
                String description = element.select("description").text();
            System.out.println(description);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TimesOfIndia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Expected output: British High Commissioner to India Sir Dominic Asquith laid a wreath at the Jallianwala Bagh memorial here on Saturday on the centenary of the massacre and said Britain "deeply regretted" the suffering caused to the victims.

Output: `<a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/uk-envoy-lays-wreath-at-jallianwala-bagh-memorial-expresses-deep-regret/articleshow/68860078.cms"><img border="0" hspace="10" align="left" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/68860078.cms" /></a>British High Commissioner to India Sir Dominic Asquith laid a wreath at the Jallianwala Bagh memorial here on Saturday on the centenary of the massacre and said Britain "deeply regretted" the suffering caused to the victims.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element` has the `nextSibling()` method, which should work:

```java
element.select("description").select("a").nextSibling().text();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer yes it is working but not with this Feed, i tried ur code and its working but when i try this in the query its not output what i expect can u edit my code ? It will be very helpful

Comment: I think i did some mistake in the parsing part

Comment: After a look at the source I see the problem:
```xml
<description>&lt;a href="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/india/rahuls-copter-denied-landing-congress-pans-didi/articleshow/68870442.cms"&gt;&lt;img border="0" hspace="10" align="left" style="margin-top:3px;margin-right:5px;" src="https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/photo/68870442.cms" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;</description>
```
As you can see, the content of the `description` element is XML encoded. So you have first do XML decode the content and then you can remove the `a` tag.
The approach in your solution is therefore really not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue using my own workaround and here's the code

**Solution**
*So i did this like this so what this code does ? I created a new document object and removed the tags then simply prints out the text, Yes this is not the best method but still works*

```
d = Jsoup.parse(desc);
        Elements a = d.select("a");
        a.remove();
        System.out.println(d.body().text());
```

**Full code**

```
try {
        Document d;
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rssfeeds/-2128936835.cms").parser(Parser.xmlParser()).get();
        Elements items = document.getElementsByTag("item");
        for (Element element : items) {
            String title = element.select("title").text();
            String link = element.select("link").text();
            String time = element.select("pubDate").text();
            String desc = element.select("description").text();
            d = Jsoup.parse(desc);
            Elements a = d.select("a");
            a.remove();
            System.out.println(d.body().text());

        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TimesOfIndia.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```